# How to assign TypeScript type to function for parameters?

Tags: typescript

I have defined a function and used TypeScript to assign types to the parameters:

```
const handleLogin = async (
    e: React.FormEvent<EventTarget>,
    navigate: NavigateFunction,
    link: string,
    data: LoginDataType,
    setError: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>,
    setLoading: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
) => {
 
    //function code
  
}
```

Right now I have provided individual types to the params but I want to create a TypeScript type like:

```
export type HandleLoginParamTypes = {
    e: React.FormEvent<EventTarget>;
    navigate: NavigateFunction;
    link: string;
    data: LoginDataType;
    setError: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
    setLoading: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
};
```

Now I want to assign the above type to the function so that in the function definition I do not have to assign types to params individually. Is that possible?

Comment: Assuming you don't actually want to _change_ the API `handleLogin`'s parameters would be a _tuple_; they're positional, not an object. In which case yes, there are various ways: https://tsplay.dev/mL56KW.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to take one parameter which is an object. So this should work and this is how it's usually done:

```
export type HandleLoginParamTypes = {
    e: React.FormEvent<EventTarget>;
    navigate: NavigateFunction;
    link: string;
    data: LoginDataType;
    setError: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
    setLoading: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
};

const handleLogin = async ({e, navigate, link, data, setError, setLoading}: HandleLoginParamTypes) => {
 
    //function code
  
}
```

Like this you also have the benefit of named parameters:

```
await handleLogin({
  e: //...,
  navigate: //...,
  link: //...,
  data: //...,
  setError: //...,
  setLoading: //...,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a type to describe:

- One parameter.
- The whole function (i.e. all its parameters and its return value).

e.g.

```js
type param1 = { foo: number };
type param2 = { bar: number };

const example = (first: param1, second: param2) => first.foo + second.bar;
```

or

```js
type ExampleFunction = (a: number, b: string) => string;
const example: ExampleFunction = (first: number, second: string) => first + second;
```

You can't describe **just** multiple parameters in a single type.

You could change the function so it takes **one** parameter which is an object:

```js
type  = { first: number; second: string; }
const example = ({first, second}: ExampleFunctionParams) => first + second;
```